# Selecting specific html tag which contains specific word with regex

Tags: php, regex

From a full of html codes, i want a specific html tag which contains a specific word.

```
<textarea>asdasdasdasd as</textarea>
<textarea>asdacccda 
sdas</textarea>
<textarea>asdasdasdasd as</textarea>
```

This is returns content between first textarea and last /textarea tag but desired result is at the middle.

```
\<textarea\>(.*)[ccc](.*)\<\/textarea\>/s
```

[image: wrong result]

Expected result;

```
<textarea>asdacccda 
sdas</textarea>
```

I've tried a couple things more but I couldn't make it work as multiline.
[image]
How can I achieve that?

Comment: [dont use regex to parse html](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5323213).

Comment: @RNar I'm not trying to parse, I just wanted to replace some contents.

Comment: With that being said, this can most likely be fixed with `?` token, to make your matching a non-greedy capture.

Comment: You don't need to escape the `/`. Try `\<textarea\>(.*)[ccc](.*)\</textarea\>`

Comment: Also remove brackets around the three c's.

Comment: Depending on input maybe [`<textarea>[^<]*?ccc[^<]*</textarea>`](https://regex101.com/r/rV7jP3/1) already sufficient.

Comment: @bobblebubble whoah, that is interesting, really neat and makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have different possibilities here.

#### The regex version

```
<textarea>                  # match <textarea>
(?:(?!</textarea>)[\s\S])*? # match anything but stop before </textarea>
ccc                         # the word you want
(?:(?!</textarea>)[\s\S])*? # same construct as above
</textarea>                 # match </textarea>
```

This uses a technique called the [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed), see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/tG3jO5/1).

---

#### Xpath queries

Another one would be to use xpath queries, ie:

```
//textarea[contains(., 'ccc')]
```

Afterwards, do whatever you want with the elements (ie remove them from the DOM).

---

#### Hints

Your original query with `[ccc]` will certainly not do what you expect it to - it is a character class which is redundant in this case (`c` will do the same).

Comment: original aim is not the ccc let's just say it is 'hot ' word. this is working thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working regex:

```
<textarea>((?:(?!<\/textarea>).)*?)ccc(.*?)<\/textarea>
```

Yes, this does seem rather uneccessary but that goes back to why using regex for HTML content is not the best idea. Here is the breakdown:

```
<textarea>((?:(?!<\/textarea>).)*?)ccc(.*?)<\/textarea>
<textarea>  -- literal match of text
          (                       )  -- your original capturing group
           (?:(?!<\/textarea>).)  -- this is a bit tricky but the idea is that you dont want it to match the textarea as part of the group
                                 ? make this token non greedy
                                   ccc   -- literal match of 3 c's, dont use square brackets, thats for doing a "one of the things in these brackets" match
                                      ( .. . . . . . >     -- this can stay the same
```

If you want to see it on regex101, see [here](https://regex101.com/r/zV7sO4/2)

Comment: does not returns expected result, you can test at https://regex101.com, thank you tough.

Comment: @siniradam, are you sure? the link that I posted seems to be working fine with your input and output. Unless you didn't actually want to capture the text before and after the `ccc`, in which case the capturing groups can be removed.

Comment: Ah, you need the `s` flag to ensure the `.` token also matches new lines.